# Add text to end of line without loading file

Tags: python

I need to store information into a very big file, in form of many dictionaries. That's not so important, is just to say that I tried to first get all the data into these dictionaries and I run out of memory (~60Gb).

Fine, so I want to add the data in the file without actually loading it in memory, by doing a loop on the lines and attaching to each line a bit of text. Is that possible? if so, how?

Comment: You need to write the modified lines to a new file line by line. Then rename that file to the name you want. Do the dictionaries span multiple lines? If so, more difficult problem...

Comment: Do you simply have a dictionary per line? In that case you could simply do an eval per line (note that this is not really too safe). Sounds like it would be a better idea to switch to a database instead though.

Comment: To clarify, you have a file consisting of many lines of dictionaries and you want to append text to the end of the line, but not inside the dictionary as a key/value?

Comment: I want to have one dictionary per line, and I want to add a key-value pair into each of them. The amount of lines is around 500k.

Comment: I could do it in a database, true, but for my particular case I want to use the text files, because I can parallelize the task.

Comment: With a database, you have better chances to parallelize the task. Most databases are _purpose-built_ for fast concurrent processing.

Comment: You cannot parallelize the writing of a sequential file, since the dictionaries (I presume you plan to encode them in JSON or similar?) are not of predictable length and therefore you would not know where to start writing any particular entry. Also, do you REALLY want to have to read a 60GB file to find the data you want? Use a database!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try any code yourself at all, what were your findings? You might go along the following approach:

```
with open('/tmp/bigfile.new', 'w') as output:
    with open('/tmp/bigfile', 'r') as input:
        while True:
            line = input.readline().strip()
            if not line:
                break
            line += ' Look ma, no hands!'
            print(line, file=output)
```

Except of course that instead of 'look ma no hands' you'd have your extra dictionary ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, the asker wants to add a key/value pair into each dictionary.  As it stands, this isn't an answer, but you could swap out the line+= for a line.update

Comment: I have to update the file many times, so I wanted to avoid rewriting the file each time, if possible. If this is the only way then ok.

Comment: @chuse: There is no way to update a file in the middle without rewriting it. You could _append_ without rewriting, but it's not your case. The answer stays correct: your best bet is to read the source file in small chunks, update each chunk, and writhe the result into a new file. At least you will not need to read everything into RAM.

Comment: But you will end up reading and writing 60GB of data, even for a single update. Surely this would be asking for trouble?

Comment: for temporary files you should use this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html

Answer (score 1):

I will recommed to use pickle to make the process easier. Using pickle there is no need to parse the dict out from the line. And you can do more than add data, you could to update it and remove it too.

```
import pickle


def update_dump_dict(dumps, key, value):
    dict_reborn = pickle.loads(dumps)
    dict_reborn[key] = value
    dumps = pickle.dumps(dict_reborn)
    return dumps


def update_line(line_number, key, value):
    with open('datafile.db', 'wb') as output:
        with open('new_datafile.db', 'rb') as input:
            line_number -= 1
            entry = input.readline() 
            if line_number == 0: 
                entry = update_dump_dict(entry, key, value)
            print(entry, file=output)
```

### Example of using pickle:

```
>>> # Dump a dict
>>> some_dict = {1: "Hello"}
>>> dumped_dict = pickle.dumps(some_dict)
>>> print(dumped_dict)
b'\x80\x03}q\x00K\x01X\x05\x00\x00\x00Helloq\x01s.'

>>> # Load the dict.
>>> dict_reborn = pickle.loads(dumped_dict)
>>> print(dict_reborn[1])
Hello
```

### What about human readability?

Well for keep human readability in the file you could use module [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

```
import json

>>> # Dump a dict
>>> some_dict = {"key": "Hello"}
>>> dumped_dict = json.dumps(some_dict)
>>> print(dumped_dict)
{"key": "Hello"}

>>> # Load the dict.
>>> dict_reborn = json.loads(dumped_dict)
>>> print(dict_reborn["key"])
Hello
```

Of course the previous version has de advantage you don't have to worry about types when you read from file.

Despite of within the recovered dictionary (with `json.loads`) all will be strings (keys and values) will be always more confortable than parsing the line to extract the data from it.

Comment: Very nice idea. Personally I find that it's a bit of a disadvantage that the db file looses human readability (and hence, usability with grep/glimpse and other text-based tools). But really neat, +1.

Comment: @KarelKubat You're right, for that you can use `json`, see the answer again.